# py:choose with list of strings

Tags: python, templates, cherrypy, genshi

I'm trying to use a choose statement inside a loop, I need to populate a table in this way:

```
<tr py:for="i in range(0,25)">
     <py:choose my_list[i]='0'>
         <py:when my_list[i]='0'><td>NOT OK</td></py:when>
         <py:otherwise><td>OK</td></py:otherwise>
     </py:choose>
...
...
</tr>
```

I have an error on the line `<py:choose...>`:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: not well-formed (invalid token): line...
```

But I cannot understand well how to use the choose statement!
If I think as C-like (and it seem to me more logical) I need to write only:

```
<tr py:for="i in range(0,25)">
     <py:choose my_list[i]>
         <py:when my_list[i]='0'><td>NOT OK</td></py:when>
         <py:otherwise><td>OK</td></py:otherwise>
     </py:choose>
...
...
</tr>
```

Can you help me?
Oh, `my_list` is a list of string. Then, if the string is `0` then for me is NOT OK, everything else is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Within the `py:choose`, you're not access the `Ith` item of my_list. Instead, `i` is set equal to the `int` from range. I assume this is a contrived example, and you're trying to access the `Ith` value of `my_list`. In this case, you should just iterate over `my_list` instead of using `range` at all.

Here's an example using your current methodolgies. The error is within `py:choose` itself:

```
from genshi.template import MarkupTemplate
template_text = """
<html xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/" >
    <tr py:for="index in range(0, 25)">
         <py:choose test="index">
             <py:when index="0"><td>${index} is NOT OK</td></py:when>
             <py:otherwise><td>${index} is OK</td></py:otherwise>
         </py:choose>
    </tr>
</html>
"""
tmpl = MarkupTemplate(template_text)
stream = tmpl.generate()
print(stream.render('xhtml'))
```

However, you should probably change `list_of_ints` to `my_list`, and iterate over it directly. **Or even better**, if you *must* know the index of each item from within `my_list`, use `enumerate`:

```
from genshi.template import MarkupTemplate
template_text = """
<html xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/" >
    <tr py:for="(index, item) in enumerate(list_of_ints)">
         <py:choose test="index">
             <py:when index="0"><td>index=${index}, item=${item} is NOT OK</td></py:when>
             <py:otherwise><td>${index}, item=${item} is OK</td></py:otherwise>
         </py:choose>
    </tr>
</html>
"""
tmpl = MarkupTemplate(template_text)
stream = tmpl.generate(list_of_ints=range(0, 25))
print(stream.render('xhtml'))
```

Of course, these examples were made to run from a python interpreter. You can modify this to work with your setup easily.

HTH

Comment: Thanks! we are near the solution... I need to know whe in the I-th sting there is written '0' then I need to py:when on the my_list[i] value and not on the index. Now I have the same error but on the py:when line, because I write:  `<py:choose test="my_list[i]">    <py:when my_list[i]='0'>...` I have even tryied with <py:when my_list[i]="'0'">

Comment: Maybe you're not understanding enumerate, or for loops. To change the second example into what you want, change `list_of_ints` to `my_list`, and replace `<py:choose test="index">` with `<py:choose test="item">`.